# jsdoc not documenting properly nodejs modules

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

I'm trying to get JSDOC (3) to properly document my NodeJS modules. While simple modules work, I can't find the way to document a slightly more complex module.

My NodeJS module has the following structure:

```
/** @module MyModule */
(function() {


     function functionToExportOne {...}

     function functionToExportTwo {...}

     /** 
      * @module MyModule.ClassToExportOne
      * @constructor 
      */
     function ClassToExportOne {

           this.classMethodOne=function() { ... }
           this.classMethodTwo=function() { ... }

     }

     /** @constructor */
     function ClassToExportTwo {

           function classMethodOne() { ... }
           function classMethodTwo() { ... }

           return /** @lends {ClassToExportTwo.prototype} */ {

               methodOne:classMethodOne,
               methodTwo:classMethodTwo
           }
     }
     /** @exports MyModule */  <--- late addition, see comments
     module.exports={
         functionOne:functionToExportOne,
         functionTwo:functionToExportTwo,
         classOne:ClassToExportOne,
         classTwo:ClassToExportTwo
     }
})()
```

Well, as you see, the module exports both methods and class constructors. Nothing very strange.

The problem is, JSDOC

- always fails to recognize the inner classes,
- Mistakes **the first** inner class methods as the (outer) module's methods,
- always skips the real exported module methods.
- The closest I've been is, in `ClassToExportOne`, when I use `@module MyModule.<className>` followed by `@constructor` (in this order) : In this case the class **is recognized**, but **only the constructor is documented**, and its methods are documented as belonging to the parent module

I've tried thousands of different combinations without success:

- defining inner classes methods with `this.method=function() {...}` (as depicted in `ClassToExportOne`) or returning an object with methods using `@lends {ClassToExportTwo.prototype}` (as depicted in `ClassToExportTwo`)
- using `@module MyModule.ClassToExportOne` in the header of each class
- defining module.exports vs exports.xxxx
- declaring inner classes `@private`, declaring everything `@private` but the exports
- moving `@module` declaration to just before the first exports (total mess then, some stuff gets promoted to "global" even though it's inside the main closure!!)
- if I add `@exports <modulename>` just before the exports declaration, the methods are documented (mixed with the class methods)

I've tried everything suggested in http://usejsdoc.org/howto-commonjs-modules.html without success.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but can't find what.

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me with jsdoc 3.3.3:

```
/**
 * Example model.
 *
 * @module model/example
 */
module.exports = (function () {
    /**
     * Constructor function.
     *
     * @exports model/example.Example
     * @constructor
     * @param {string} id
     */
    var example = function Example(id) {
        this.id = id;
    };

    /**
     * Returns the ID.
     *
     * @memberof model/example.Example
     * @returns {string} the id
     */
    example.prototype.getId = function () {
        return this.id;
    };

    return example;
}());
```

and an example creating an instance of the model:

```
var example = new Example("ID");
console.log(example.getId());
```

Answer (score 3):

I hate to answer my own question, but with a little more trial and error I got quite satisfactory results. Please feel free to comment if this is a correct approach, but the fact is the documentation is now properly generated :)

The key seems to be to use `@exports <modulename>.<classname>` before `@constructor` , this way the class appear in the index under "classes", and with its methods properly documented **IF the methods are declared with** `this.method=function() {...}`

I still would like to find a way to make this work, if at all possible, for the case depicted in ClassToExportTwo , sometimes it's very convenient for me to define a class like this, specially for long classes that call private methods so I can avoid totally using "this" inside the class (optimization).

Well here's the template that works for me:

```
/** @module MyModule */
(function() {


     function functionToExportOne {...}

     function functionToExportTwo {...}

     /** works !!
      * @exports MyModule.ClassToExportOne
      * @constructor 
      */
     function ClassToExportOne {

           function innerMethod() { ... }

           // this works: assigning methods to this

           this.classMethodOne=function() { ... }
           this.classMethodTwo=function() { ... }

     }

     /** does not work
      * @exports MyModule.ClassToExportTwo
      * @constructor 
      */         
     function ClassToExportTwo {

           function classMethodOne() { ... }
           function classMethodTwo() { ... }

           // this DOES NOT WORK !! Methods get mixed with parent module
           return  {

               methodOne:classMethodOne,
               methodTwo:classMethodTwo
           }
     }

     // no more @exports here as it duplicates definitions in the docs
     module.exports={
         /** blah blah function description */
         functionOne:functionToExportOne,
         /** blah blah function description */
         functionTwo:functionToExportTwo,
         /** blah blah function description */
         classOne:ClassToExportOne,
         /** blah blah function description */
         classTwo:ClassToExportTwo
     }
})()
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you. I couldn't get JSDOC to generate the documentation correctly for my child classes when the Parent class was in it's own module.